# How to configure docker compose for Rasa X (with specific model)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rasa, rasa-x

Im trying to run use docker-compose to run the rasa server alongwith the actions server.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  rasa:
    image: rasa/rasa:latest-full
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command:
      - x
  action_server:
    image: rasa/rasa-sdk:latest
    volumes:
      - ./actions:/app/actions
```

Currently i get two errors on doing `docker-compose up`

```
Failed to register package 'actions.actions'.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasax'
```

Here is the complete trace:

```
docker-compose up
Recreating wlbot_rasa_1        ... done
Starting wlbot_action_server_1 ... done
Attaching to wlbot_action_server_1, wlbot_rasa_1
action_server_1  | 2019-08-22 19:38:10 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server...
action_server_1  | 2019-08-22 19:38:10 ERROR    rasa_sdk.executor  - Failed to register package 'actions.actions'.
action_server_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
action_server_1  |   File "/app/rasa_sdk/executor.py", line 184, in register_package
action_server_1  |     self._import_submodules(package)
action_server_1  |   File "/app/rasa_sdk/executor.py", line 171, in _import_submodules
action_server_1  |     package = importlib.import_module(package)
action_server_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
action_server_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
action_server_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
action_server_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
action_server_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
action_server_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'actions.actions'
action_server_1  | 2019-08-22 19:38:10 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Action endpoint is up and running. on ('0.0.0.0', 5055)
rasa_1           | Traceback (most recent call last):
rasa_1           |   File "/usr/local/bin/rasa", line 10, in <module>
rasa_1           |     sys.exit(main())
rasa_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasa/__main__.py", line 76, in main
rasa_1           |     cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
rasa_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasa/cli/x.py", line 291, in rasa_x
rasa_1           |     run_locally(args)
rasa_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasa/cli/x.py", line 308, in run_locally
rasa_1           |     from rasax.community import local  # pytype: disable=import-error
rasa_1           | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasax'
wlbot_rasa_1 exited with code 1
```

I can't find in the docs about how to configure this for `Rasa X` instead of `rasa run` and also specify a particular model. 
Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose for rasa, you have to pull image rasa/rasa-x (which contains rasa + rasa x). For the actions, try to specify the file (not the directory) like "./actions.py:/app/actions/actions.py"